# doas on FreeBSD does not respect 5 minute timeout

Tags: freebsd, sudo

I've setup doas to run on FreeBSD 11.1 as per [these](https://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/doas-mastery) instructions and added the following line to my doas.conf:

> permit persist :wheel

I've noticed that I need to insert my password every time I run doas, ie, it's not respecting the 5 minute limit for password expiration.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the following in [man doas.conf](https://github.com/slicer69/doas/blob/master/doas.conf.5#L52):

> persist
>
> After the user successfully authenticates, do not ask for a password again for some time. Works on OpenBSD only, persist is not available on Linux or                                                               FreeBSD.

The most important part is: *"persist is not available on ... FreeBSD"*. I think it will not work on FreeBSD.

Comment: Well, I deserved that.